# Writing to binary file in C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, file

I have 2 applications. One in C++ (windows) open a binary file and only reads from it, i use:

```
fstream m_fsDataIN.open("C:\TTT", ios::in | ios::binary | ios::app);
```

and the second application (is in C#) opens the file and writes to it. I use:

```
byte[] b = ... //have a binary data
System.IO.BinaryWriter bw = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(
                        System.IO.File.Open(@"C:\TTT",
                        System.IO.FileMode.Append,
                        System.IO.FileAccess.Write,
                        System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite));
bw.Write(b);
bw.Flush();
bw.Close();
```

The problem is that the 8 first bytes are written incorrectly, comparing to what appears in the `b` array.

When I open the file in the C# application, using `System.IO.FileMode.Append` it works OK.

I checked in the application and it writes wrong 8 bytes.

I want to add that the first 8 bytes are 2 counters that each was created using `IPAddressHostToNetworkAddress`.

I think that the problem is in the C++ application, in how I open the file.

Help, 
Thnaks

Comment: Might help if you show us your code that uses `IPAddressHostToNetworkAddress`. Sounds like an endianness issue to me, anyway.

Comment: Roman: the open looks OK but you don't show how you read from the stream. Reading from a stream may be formatted (using operator<< ) or not; that can make all the difference. Could you post those parts as well?

Comment: Reading:
std::vector<char> m_vctDataIN; 
m_vctDataIN.resize(1000);
m_fsDataIN.read(&m_vctDataIN[], 1000);
int nReadBytes  = m_fsDataIN.gcount();
m_nBytesInBuffer += nReadBytes;

***I found a nother thing:
When The C++ application is down the C# application writes correctly. When it is up it writes wrong.

Comment: When I didn't read from the file in the C++ application it worked OK, so it must be in the read part.

Comment: So are you saying that the C++ application changed the file when it tried to read it?  Have you verified this by looking at the contents of the file in a binary editor before and after trying to read it?

Comment: I can't make sense out of the apparent contradiction between these two statements in your question. 
This suggests that you the writer part is "wrong":
"I checked in the application and it writes wrong 8 bytes."
This suggests that the reader par is "wrong":
"I think that the problem is in the C++ application, in how I open the file."
Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the C++ application.
The program contained configuration which produced another file handler.
Using Process Explorer I found out about it. 
Removing the configuration of that extra file handler resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've opened it just fine. But how do you read it? I think you need to call `ntohl` on the `C++` side.

Comment: Reading: std::vector<char> m_vctDataIN; m_vctDataIN.resize(1000); m_fsDataIN.read(&m_vctDataIN[], 1000); int nReadBytes = m_fsDataIN.gcount(); m_nBytesInBuffer += nReadBytes; ***I found a nother thing: When The C++ application is down the C# application writes correctly. When it is up it writes wrong

Comment: yes, but C# application writes and C++ reads, except in the beginning that the C# make one read and close the file.

Comment: Well, I give up, it's either something trivial or it turns too platform-specific and the platform is not my native environment.